# AddMonths() in Eval()

Tags: asp.net, datetime, data-binding, eval, vb.net-to-c#

Here is the Code I have for a Label I wrote in ASP.NET:

```
<asp:Label ID="enddate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eeval("startdate")).AddMonths(Eval("sublength") %>' />
```

Basically I Want to Convert this to C# but am having issues with it.

This code gets the startdate from a bound field then uses another boundfield sublength to get it's value

IE 12 or 24 Months Hence the addmonths (Eval "Sublength"))  though i am not sure how to convert this to C# to dynamically adjust the value of the label
I realize that eval would become Eval but apart from that i am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your VB.NET `eval` is just shorthand for the framework method `DataBinder.Eval`. Use this framework method in C#. On top of that you'll need to explicitly cast the values being returned by `DataBinder.Eval` and use proper case.

```
((DateTime)DataBinder.Eval("startdate")).AddMonths((int)DataBinder.Eval("sublength"))
```